# Exact Online Authorization

Tags: azure, exact-online

I have registered two apps(app target as 'Test') on Exact online,redirect url for one of these application is azure hosted site and other with locally hosted site.

App with locally hosted site authorizes properly and returns token successfully.
however,it fails to authorize app with azure hosted site.
OAuth2 ProtocolVersion is V20.

Can anybody help with this?
Do we need to do some settings on azure portal for Oauth2 authentication for third party software's like Exact online in this case,to get request authorized properly?

Thanks in advance.

Code sample:

## region Authorize request

```
     private static readonly ExactOnlineOAuthClient OAuthClient = new ExactOnlineOAuthClient();
     private Boolean AuthorizeClient()
    {
        OAuthClient.Authorize(returnUri);
        return (OAuthClient.Authorization != null);
    }
    #endregion
    
    #region ExactOnlineOAuthClient Class
    public ExactOnlineOAuthClient()
        : base(CreateAuthorizationServerDescription(), ClientIdentifier(), ClientSecret())
    {
        ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ClientSecret());
    }

   
     private static AuthorizationServerDescription CreateAuthorizationServerDescription()
    {
        var baseUri = "https://start.exactonline.nl";
        var uri = new Uri(baseUri.EndsWith("/") ? baseUri : baseUri + "/");
        var serverDescription = new AuthorizationServerDescription
        {
            AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri(uri, "api/oauth2/auth"),
            TokenEndpoint = new Uri(uri, "api/oauth2/token")
        };

        return serverDescription;
    }
    private static string ClientIdentifier()
    {
        return "ClientIdentifier"; //valid client id
    }
    
    private static string ClientSecret()
    {
        return "ClientSecret"; //valid client secret
    }
    
    private void Authorize(Uri returnUri)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Authorization == null)
            {
                Authorization = ProcessUserAuthorization();
                if (Authorization == null)
                {
                    // Kick off authorization request
                    RequestUserAuthorization(null, returnUri);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (AccessTokenHasToBeRefreshed())
                {
                    RefreshAuthorization(Authorization);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Some code might be useful to see what is going on.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: I am receiving this error from ProcessUserAuthorization function:

DotnetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException : Error occured while sending a direct message or getting the response and
Inner exception is The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized.

Comment: That usually means the redirect url is passed in incorrectly.

Comment: I am sure that i am passing correct redirect url. Can you think of any other reason?

Comment: This can even be at the level of too many slashes. It should match *exactly*.

Comment: ok, i will check once again.